# MD5 from NSData is always diffrent

Tags: ios, md5, nsdata, md5-file

I create an MD5 of a file that is deployed with my bundle to decide if I need to import it.
My problem is that when I create the MD5 is always different. Even when I call the MD5 method 10 times in a loop with the same data, I got different results.

Here is my MD% method:

```
- (NSString*)hashForData:(NSData*)data
{
    unsigned char md5Buffer[CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    CC_MD5((__bridge const void*)(data), (CC_LONG)data.length, md5Buffer);
    NSMutableString* output = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH * 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
        [output appendFormat:@"%02x", md5Buffer[i]];

    return output;
}

- (NSData*)data
{
    if (!_data) {
        _data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:_path];
    }
    return _data;
}
```

Any idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't that be:

```
CC_MD5((__bridge const void*)([data bytes]), (CC_LONG)[data length], md5Buffer);
//                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

(i.e. you are calculating the MD5 hash of the `NSData` object (and adjacent memory) instead of the data *within* the `NSData` object).

Comment: Using a selector vs a property doesn't matter at all. But you definitely can't just cast the object to a pointer.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII It does to me.

Comment: you are absolutely right. CC_MD5([data bytes], (CC_LONG)data.length, md5Buffer);